# Angular js dynamic grid headers after importing JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

From the following code, i will get the the grid having columns **Name, Gender and Company**.

Now how will i dynamically change the Grid column names : Like I want **FirstName** instead of **Name**

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html ng-app="app">
  <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-touch.js">     </script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-animate.js"> </script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"> </script>
  <script src="/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
  <script src="/release/ui-grid-unstable.css"></script>
  <script> 
   var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.importer']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableGridMenu: true,
    data: 'data',
    importerDataAddCallback: function ( grid, newObjects ) {
    $scope.data = $scope.data.concat( newObjects );
    },
   onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){ 
   $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
   }
  };
  }]);
 </script>
  </head>
   <body>
     <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-importer class="grid"></div>
     </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**Suppoese this is the json file**

```
[{
  "Name":"John Smith",
  "Gender":"male",
  "Company":"TestIcon"
 },
 {
  "Name":"Jane Doe",
  "Gender":"female",
  "Company":"FastTruck"
 }]
```

From the following code, i will get the the grid having **columns Name, Gender and Company**.

Now how will i dynamically change the Grid column names : Like I want **FirstName** instead of **Name**

Guys Please help me in sorting this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want:

```
columnDefs: [
   { field: 'Name', displayName: 'FirstName' },
   { field: 'Gender' },
   { field: 'Company' }
]
```